# How can i access the child attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the object returning from the lib

```
Updates(
    updates=[
        UpdateMessageID(
            id=11879, 
            random_id=8864026361180002582), 
        UpdateReadChannelInbox(
            channel_id=1330097005, 
            max_id=11879, 
            still_unread_count=0, 
            pts=21579, 
            folder_id=None), 
        UpdateNewChannelMessage(
            message=MessageService(
                id=11879, 
                peer_id=PeerChannel(
```

I can access the updates by calling result.updates
How can I get the id of result.updates.UpdateMessageID.id ?

This is the error message

> 'list' object has no attribute 'UpdateMessageID'

Comment: There is no way for us to know what your structures `UpdateMessageID` etc looks like with that code snippet. Please try and include more of your code.

Comment: is this Telegram API? What package do you use? Show us [MRE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updates` attribute is a list, so you have to select an element first, even if it is the *only* element:

```
results.updates[0].id
```

If there are, in fact, multiple `UpdateMessageID` values in the list, you'll need some way to figure out which one you actually want. That may involve iterating over them all:

```
for message_id in result.updates:
    if message_id.id == THE_ONE_I_WANT:
        ...
```